# Alternate methods to prove $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d) \geq 16$ if $abcd =1$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I found this question some time ago in an Elementary Olympiad book:

> If $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers such that $abcd =1$, then prove that $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d) \geq 16$.

Evidently this was a direct consequence of Hölder's inequality, so I merely gave the following proof.

$$(1^4+(a^{\frac{1}{4}})^4)(1^4+(b^{\frac{1}{4}})^4)(1^4+(c^{\frac{1}{4}})^4)(1^4+(d^{\frac{1}{4}})^4) \geq (1+(abcd)^{\frac{1}{4}})^4 $$
$$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d) \geq (1+1)^4$$
$$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d) \geq 16$$

QED.

---

However, I was requested by my instructor to try the problem again using only the AM-GM inequality or the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, because it is supposedly solvable using only those two.

At this point I expanded the expression believing that all the terms so formed would be of the degree $4$, and would, when taken together in groups, yield a power of $abcd$ on the GM side, which could then be added.

Doing so, however, I only get the weaker result that $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d) \geq 14$.

I would appreciate a hint for this tantalizing problem.

Comment: If $a,\ldots,d$ are positive **integers** with $abcd=1$ then $a=\cdots=d=1$.

Comment: More similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/547505?lq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it means the following way.

By AM-GM
$$\prod_{cyc}(1+a)=$$
$$=1+(a+b+c+d)+(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)+$$
$$+(abc+abd+acd+bcd)+abcd\geq$$
$$\geq1+4+6+4+1=16.$$

Comment: Oof, looks like I made an elementary mistake. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Lt. Commander. Data You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $1+x \ge 2\sqrt{x}$. Do this to each variable , and multiply !

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM, $1+a\ge 2\sqrt{a}.$
So $$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d)\ge 16 \sqrt{abcd}=16$$

Answer (score 3):

I guess the following is the easiest one:

Via the AM-GM inequality,
$$1+a\geq 2\sqrt a$$
Similarly, obtain for $b,c,d$ and multiply:
$$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d)\geq 16 \sqrt{abcd}$$
Substitute $abcd=1$ and you are done.